# Seamlessly updating a postgres database - schemas, rename, how?

Tags: postgresql, schema, rename

Actually a simple question, but I wasn't able to find any good conclusive answer.

Assuming a production database foo_prd, and a newer version of the same foo_new (on the same server) that is supposed to replace the old one. What is the cleanest way to seamlessly switch from _prd to _new?

RENAME-ing the databases would require to disconnect the current users via their pid. That would take down some requests, and new users might connect during the process. I was thinking of creating the tables of the new database as different SCHEMA and then change the search_path, e.g. from `"$user",prd` to `"$user",new,prd`.

What could possibly go wrong? Do you have any better suggestions? Am I taking the wrong approach altogether?

Comment: Not sure that renaming would really require a forced disconnect. I think (not tested) the rename would wait until all connections are gone. Of course the two renames should be done in a single transaction.

Comment: Nope, it fails with an error. This I have tested. :)

Comment: I think the traditional way to make large changes in production is to script schema and data updates, backup, test offline, and apply on the existing database. That doesn't require keeping two sets of data around, or having the old database read-only for a while.

Comment: Oh, read-only is ok. Any downtime is not. - It is hardly accessed for writing anyway. But updating the data *over* the existing ones is difficult, because the update needs to be atomic and no clear, granular mapping exists what to overwrite and what to delete. (specifically: having half a map update for geodata is a horrible idea. And you can't just replace/overwrite in small areas with new roads being added and old roads disappearing) That said, I might be missing something very simple.

Comment: @relet can I suggest calling your new schema something other than `new`?

Comment: Certainly, thank you. :) I just chose these identifiers here as anything more specific would make little sense in the context.

Comment: I think your question and my answer would be a better fit over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), are you willing to consider self-flagging for migration there? I see you already have an account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as you suggest: create the tables of the new database as different schema and then change the search_path.

But also create a user with the same name as the new schema and test everything before changing the search_path by logging in as this user with each of your apps - the new schema will be first in that user's search_path by default because the name matches.

Finally, take care when you come to drop the old schema - I suggest renaming first in case anything refers to it's objects using a qualified reference (eg `prd.table` or `prd.function`). After a few days/weeks it can then be dropped with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I would version my schema, and change my app to point to the new schema when ready.

Comment: Thanks. I agree this would work, and I have done that in the past - just that in our case 'the app' is a decent number of small, agile services distributed over several machines.